# Are user names in the audits completely random?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-audit

Recently I passed some reputation threshold and started receiving tasks of reviewing suggested edits/first posts/late answers.

Among the first kind of tasks, there are some (as I guess) fake suggested edits, which insert several bizarre words and sentences. After I reject them as a spam/vandalism, the system congratulates me on passing an audit successfully.

There was a strange coincidence though. I have passed so far three such tests, two of which were "authored" by the same [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269518/ivan-neretin). (I know him well, otherwise I wouldn't have noticed probably.) A very unlikely coincidence! Therefore, the question, just out of curiosity:

> Are the user names chosen completely at random for such audits?

**Update**: I have just received a fourth audit check. The same user! Now I don't believe this is a coincidence. And my guess from the comment is not correct, as the user is offline now. Either he is somehow attached to me (or someone who is organizing these checks read this post and decided to add some mistery).

**Update 2** A new audit, the same user! What is going on? I've added some pictures (unfortunately, the very first is lost).

[image: Second audit]
[image: Fourth audit]
[image: Fifth audit]

Comment: I would guess they are at best pseudorandom.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Such a coincidence seems even less likely for pseudorandom. Seems that the user name is chosen from those active at the moment (I checked, and, indeed, that user was suggesting an edit on one occasion of the audit and was posting a comment, on another) and having rep<2000.

Comment: The audit system has become sentient and wants to train you to reject Ivan's suggestions without looking at them. No idea why it wants to do that, however.

Comment: Maybe the system is trying to test ability to decouple subjectivity. Measures who have I upvoted and am likely to be positively biased against. If in a review position, will I be able to stay cool and make an objective/unbiased ruling?